# Bluetooth Permission Request Alert in iOS 13, Yet App Doesn't Use Bluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bluetooth, ios13

When I run my app on iOS 13, I am getting the Bluetooth permission request alert popping up. I have searched the project and nowhere in it, or the pods, is `CoreBluetooth` being imported or called in any way.

I do have some third party libraries, which don't appear to be accessing bluetooth. What could be causing this permission alert?

Comment: Isn't the library added to the project Build Phases? https://imgur.com/a/gIDWE9t

Comment: The only thing listed there is the pods

Comment: The Bugsee library was causing the Bluetooth permission request to display. It likely does some sort of Bluetooth monitoring internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bugsee team member is here.

In the latest versions of our iOS SDK we've added BugseeMonitorBluetoothStatusKey launch option (for more info refer to https://docs.bugsee.com/sdk/ios/configuration/) which by default is set to NO. So, to prevent that dialog from popping up, make sure you're using latest SDK and not setting that option.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the `BugseeMonitorBluetoothStatusKey` key in this build: `https://download.bugsee.com/sdk/ios/Bugsee-stable.zip`. I do see: `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL monitorBluetoothStatus;`

Comment: That key indeed was missing, and we've put it back in our latest version at the moment of writing (1.23.12).

Comment: Hey @krassx I am using pod version 1.21.5 of Bugsee on iOS using BugseeOptions.default() and I am still being asked for this bluetooth permission. I have removed Bugsee as a pod and the bluetooth requirement disappeared.

Comment: @CoreyPett Please, update your SDK to the latest version, or, at least, to 1.23.11 where is's known to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked, there was no `BugseeMonitorBluetoothStatusKey` in the latest stable build for iOS. So I had to do something like this:

```
let options = BugseeOptions.default()
// Bluetooth is now off by default, but if you wanted to manually tweak it, set this
options.monitorBluetoothStatus = false 
Bugsee.launch(token:"your token goes here", options: options)
```